# Resize with JavaScript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to resize multiple boxes together using javascript or jquery.

For this purpose, I wrote a code that changes the size of the desired box by adding or removing the class.

The code I wrote works correctly but the only problem is that it only affects the first box and the other boxes don't react at all.

The codes I wrote are as follows:

```js
let Box = document.querySelector(".box");
let btn_one = document.querySelector(".btn_one");

btn_one.addEventListener("click", function () {
        $(Box).removeClass("box_two");
        $(Box).removeClass("box_three");
})

let btn_two = document.querySelector(".btn_two");

btn_two.addEventListener("click", function () {
        $(Box).addClass("box_two");
        $(Box).removeClass("box_three");
})

let btn_three = document.querySelector(".btn_three");

btn_three.addEventListener("click", function () {
        $(Box).addClass("box_three");
        $(Box).removeClass("box_two");
})
```

```css
.main-BOX {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 3rem auto 5rem;
    padding: 10px;
}

.btn_one,
.btn_two,
.btn_three {
    font-size: 35px;
    background: #93ff8a;
    color: #f87070;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
    width: 90%;
    height: 190px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    background: #61cc8b;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.box_two {
    width: 30%;
    height: 240px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #3add89;
    background: #2572e9;
}


.box_three {
    width: 90%;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #a2dd3a;
    background: #e925dd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main-BOX">

        <button class="btn_one">1</button>
        <button class="btn_two">2</button>
        <button class="btn_three">3</button>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="box"></div>

    </section>
```

Comment: I updated my answer a bit to give another example of simplifying the Event Listener. No need for three separate functions (and removes JQuery )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to stick to JQuery for this. In vanilla JS, `let Box = document.querySelector(".box")` only selects the first element with the class `.box` it finds. You're better off doing `let Box = $('.box');` JQuery will select all of them.

The `let btn_xxx = document.querySelector(".btn_xxx");` are fine, because there are only one of each class in your code.

```js
let Box = $('.box');
let btn_one = document.querySelector(".btn_one");
let btn_two = document.querySelector(".btn_two");
let btn_three = document.querySelector(".btn_three");

btn_one.addEventListener("click", function () {
        Box.removeClass("box_two");
        Box.removeClass("box_three");
})


btn_two.addEventListener("click", function () {
        Box.addClass("box_two");
        Box.removeClass("box_three");
})


btn_three.addEventListener("click", function () {
        Box.addClass("box_three");
        Box.removeClass("box_two");
})
```

```css
.main-BOX {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 3rem auto 5rem;
    padding: 10px;
}

.btn_one,
.btn_two,
.btn_three {
    font-size: 35px;
    background: #93ff8a;
    color: #f87070;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
    width: 90%;
    height: 190px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    background: #61cc8b;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.box_two {
    width: 30%;
    height: 240px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #3add89;
    background: #2572e9;
}


.box_three {
    width: 90%;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #a2dd3a;
    background: #e925dd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main-BOX">

        <button class="btn_one">1</button>
        <button class="btn_two">2</button>
        <button class="btn_three">3</button>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="box"></div>

    </section>
```

### EDIT

Here's a version that simplifies the `click` event listener, uses no JQuery, and uses `data` attributes instead of classes to assign the styles.

```js
let Box = document.querySelectorAll('.box'),
  button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

// For each button
button.forEach(btn => { // arrow function btn is the button that was clicked
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => { // e is the event of the listener.
    // For each box
    Box.forEach(box => { // the box element
      // Set the data-size attribute of the box to the content of the data-num attribute of the button that was clicked.
      box.setAttribute('data-size', e.target.dataset.num);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.main-BOX {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 3rem auto 5rem;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: #93ff8a;
  color: #f87070;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box,
[data-size="one"] {
  width: 90%;
  height: 190px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  background: #61cc8b;
  margin: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.box[data-size="two"] {
  width: 30%;
  height: 240px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #3add89;
  background: #2572e9;
}

.box[data-size="three"] {
  width: 90%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #a2dd3a;
  background: #e925dd;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-BOX">

  <button class="btn" data-num="one">1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-num="two">2</button>
  <button class="btn" data-num="three">3</button>

  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: `$(Box)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Unmitigated - yep, just caught that! Good call. I would also argue that all the different `addEventListner('click')` functions are necessary, but that comes down to code clean up.

Answer (score -2):

I'm hoping this will help give you a starting point.

Here's a React Hook I use that reacts to the Window Size:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Rectangle } from 'utils/globalTypes';

/**
 * This is a React Hook implementation of the window.onresize function.
 * 
 * @param {number} horizontalMargin
 * @param {number} verticalMargin
 * @returns windowSize: Rectangle
 */
export const useWindowSize = (horizontalMargin: number = 0,  verticalMargin: number = 0) => {
  const getWindowSize = React.useCallback(() => {
    const {innerWidth, innerHeight} = window;
    return {width: innerWidth - horizontalMargin, height: innerHeight - verticalMargin};
  }, [horizontalMargin, verticalMargin]);

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = React.useState<Rectangle>(getWindowSize());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowResize = () => {
      setWindowSize(getWindowSize());
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize); // Cleanup function
    };
  }, [getWindowSize]);

  return [ windowSize ] as const;
};
```

P.S. The imported type is simply this:

```
export type Rectangle = {
  width: number,
  height: number
};
```

I know that you didn't mention React but hopefully the code will still be helpful.

Comment: How does this remotely answer the question?